# separate 2D gaussian kernel into two 1D kernels

Tags: numpy, convolution

A gaussian kernel is calculated and checked that it can be separable by looking in to the rank of the kernel.

```
kernel = gaussian_kernel(kernel_size,sigma)
print(kernel)

[[ 0.01054991  0.02267864  0.0292689   0.02267864  0.01054991]
 [ 0.02267864  0.04875119  0.06291796  0.04875119  0.02267864]
 [ 0.0292689   0.06291796  0.0812015   0.06291796  0.0292689 ]
 [ 0.02267864  0.04875119  0.06291796  0.04875119  0.02267864]
 [ 0.01054991  0.02267864  0.0292689   0.02267864  0.01054991]]

 rank = np.linalg.matrix_rank(kernel)

if rank == 1:
    print('The Kernel is separable')
else:
    print('The kernel is not separable')
```

Now I believe the separation is not correct. I am doing it in the following manner:

```
 u,s,v = np.linalg.svd(kernel)
 k1 = (u[:,0] * np.sqrt(s[0]))[np.newaxis].T
 k2 = v[:,0] * np.sqrt(s[0])
```

Then I multiplied the above two kernels to get the original kernel back. But I did not get it.

```
if not  np.all(k1 * k2 == kernel):
    print('k1 * k2 is not equal to kernel')
```

I assume that the separation that I am trying to do using svd and further is not correct. Some explanation would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

matrix rank 1 means that all the rows are either zero or the same up to scaling and the same is true for columns. They are also up to scaling equal to the two factors.
Therefore you can recover them using something like

```
I,J = np.unravel_index(np.abs(kernel).argmax(), kernel.shape)
f1 = np.nansum(kernel / (kernel[None,:,J]@kernel),1,keepdims=True)
f2 = np.nansum(kernel / (kernel@kernel[I,:,None]),0,keepdims=True)
scaling = np.sqrt(np.abs(kernel).sum()/np.abs(f1*f2).sum())
f1 *= scaling * np.sign(f1[I,0]) * np.sign(kernel[I,J])
f2 *= scaling * np.sign(f2[0,J])
```

Note that most of the complexity comes from my trying to average as many data as possible. A simpler but I'd assume numerically not quite as stable method would be

```
I,J = np.unravel_index(np.abs(kernel).argmax(), kernel.shape)
f1 = kernel[:,J,None]
f2 = kernel[None,I,:] / kernel[I,J]
```

Of course, your method also works once you get the indexing right:

```
k1 = u[:,0,None] * np.sqrt(s[0])
k2 = v[None,0,:] * np.sqrt(s[0])

np.allclose(kernel, k1*k2)
# True
```